# PHP query to show rows without dates when restricting query with two WHERE clauses

Tags: php, mysql

The code below echoes out a table with rows for the next 90 days, which is what I want.  It only diplays "deals" for the dates that have deals.  The other dates are blank, which is also what I want.

I would like to limit the table to only display deals `WHERE cityid = '$cityid'`.  However, when I try to add this to the query, it omits rows for dates that do not have deals.

How can I limit the query to `WHERE cityid = '$cityid'` and still show rows for dates that do not have deals?

```
$sqlStr = 
    "SELECT c.dt, d.deal, d.dealid, d.datescheduled, d.cityid
    FROM calendar_table c
    LEFT JOIN deals d ON d.datescheduled = c.dt
    WHERE c.dt > NOW()
    ORDER BY c.dt ASC
    LIMIT 90";

echo "<table class=\"samplesrecs\">";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $dt = new DateTime($row["dt"], $tzFrom);  
    $dt->setTimezone($tzTo);

    echo '<tr class="class3a">';

    echo '<td style= "border-left:2px solid #ce0f07; 
            border-right:2px solid #ce0f07; 
            border-top:2px solid #ce0f07;" 
            class="sitename1">
        <a href="http://www.domain.com/login/deal.php?date='.urlencode($row["dt"]).'&cityid='.urlencode($cityid).'">'.$dt->format('l, F j, Y').'</a>
        </td>';
    echo '<td style="border-left:2px solid #ce0f07; 
            border-right:2px solid #ce0f07; 
            border-top:2px solid #ce0f07;" 
            class="sitename1">
        <a href="http://www.domain.com/login/deal.php?date='.urlencode($row["dt"]).'&cityid='.urlencode($cityid).'&dealid='.urlencode($row["dealid"]).'">'.$row["deal"].'</a>
        </td>';
}

echo '</tr>';
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: One option is to include the additional predicate in the `ON` clause of the LEFT JOIN operation, rather than the `WHERE` clause. (Adding that predicate to the `WHERE` clause effectively negates the "outerness" of the JOIN operation.) Another option would be to use a slightly different predicate in the `WHERE` clause... `AND (d.city ='$city' OR d.city IS NULL)`... but that's slightly different in that the resultset would also include rows from `deals` that have a null value for `city`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an additional constraint on your `JOIN` clause:

```
SELECT c.dt, d.deal, d.dealid, d.datescheduled, d.cityid
FROM calendar_table c
LEFT JOIN deals d ON (
    d.datescheduled = c.dt
    AND d.cityid = "mycity"
)
WHERE c.dt > NOW() 
ORDER BY c.dt ASC
LIMIT 90
```

This will display all dates, but only show deals if the occur with the specified city.

Comment: This is an example of SQL.  If you're wrapping it verbatim in double quotes, then yes, you will have a parse error.  Please read and understand the code, don't just copy + paste it in blindly.

Comment: I replaced your "mycity" with '$cityid'.   The table calendar_table has no field for cityid.

Comment: Actually, I got it to work... thanks.  Not sure what I did wrong the first time...

Answer (score 1):

add it to your join

```
$sqlStr = "SELECT c.dt, d.deal, d.dealid, d.datescheduled, d.cityid
             FROM calendar_table c
             LEFT JOIN deals d ON d.datescheduled = c.dt AND d.cityid = '$cityid'
            WHERE c.dt > NOW() 
         ORDER BY c.dt ASC
         LIMIT 90";
```

Comment: This returns a blank page